# Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I use the library  `react-native-scrollable-tab-view` to achieve tab view.

`VideoScreen` hook componet nested `BasicView` tab view hook componet.

VideoScreen:

```
import ScrollableTabView from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import BasicView from './BasicView';

VideoScreen = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollableTabView>
      <BasicView tabLabel={"Basic"} />
    </ScrollableTabView>
  );
};

export default VideoScreen;
```

BasicView:

```
BasicView = () => {

// basicVideos is my list array data.

const renderVideos = ({item}) => {
  const {id} = item;

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

return (
    <View>
      <View style={{height: 16}} />
      {basicVideos.map((value, index) => {
        const {id, videos, title} = value;

        return (
          <View key={index} style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
            <Text style={styles.categoryTitle}>{title}</Text>
            <FlatList
              style={styles.flatSection}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              horizontal={true}
              data={videos}
              renderItem={renderVideos}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

export default BasicView;
```

The code shows `Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead` If I remove `<FlatList />` , the warning is gone,
but I don't know why. How do I fix this warning ?

Comment: What is `renderVideos`? Can you share a more complete code example?

Comment: Sure, I update the question, `renderVideos` just return simple View.

Comment: If you render a dummy component in `renderVideos`, i.e. `<Text>Test</Text>` does it still have issue? I guess you need to trace into whatever is in the React DOMTree of the `FlatList` component until you find what it is.

Comment: Yes, dummy data with `<Text>Test</Text>` still has the issue.